Airflow run same task with pause for 24 hours
Is there a way to pause a task for 24 hours then run the same task again?
I want to write a dag that pull data from api, but the api have limit of data I can pull in a day so I need to wait for 24 hours to pull the data again.
so I want the dag to work like
task1--> dag pause for 24 hours --> task1

You can use Cron Presets such as @daily for this use case.
Your sample DAG would like the following:
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
@dag(schedule=@daily, start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1), catchup=False)
def sample_dag():
    @task
    def sample_task():
        print(f"Sample DAG")

    task()
sample_dag()

